# How to wrap elements inside of body dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to wrap the elements inside of the `body` by `<div id="wrap">` dynamically, using jQuery/JavaScript. The final result has to be:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <!-- open div #wrap here -->
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">....</div>
    </div>
    <!-- close div #wrap here, before close body tag -->
</body>
```

Should I create the div  and after add the content that already exists inside body? How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method, as below:

```
$('body').children().wrapAll("<div id='wrap'>");
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ucunin/1/edit)**

Comment: Easiest way! I used your suggestion. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

First you would want to grab the current HTML and store it in a variable, then the use of the `.html()`method will do wonders:

```
$(function(){
    var bod = $("body"), current_html = bod.html();
    bod.html("<div id=\"wrap\">" + current_html + "</div>");
});
```

Comment: Not a problem, you could write it in one line as well, although it's not very pretty: `$("body").html("<div id=\"wrap\">" + $("body").html() + "</div>");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body).html("<div id='wrap'>...</div>")
```

Comment: This erases the contents of the body and replaces with that string. Not really what the question was asking.

Answer (score 0):

wrapAll should produce several div tags. I would have used wrapInner instead.

```
$('body').wrapInner('<div id="wrap">');
```